# ddply with which.max function

Tags: r, plyr

You may be able to help me: For each ID, I wish to extract the largest "a" value that has the largest "b" value. In other words, I wish to scan through the "b" values, identify the highest (here b=40). 
If several "a" have the same highest "b" value (here a=20 and a=30), then I wish to select the highest "a" value (here a=30).

Here is what I have done so far:

```
df<- data.frame(ID=c('1','1','1','1','1','1'), a=c('10','20','30','10','2','30'), b=c('10','20','30','10','40', "40"))

library(plyr)

opt <- ddply(df,.(ID),summarise,
             a=a[which.max(b)])
opt

ID a
1  2
```

but, I don't get:

```
ID a
1  30
```

I'd greatly appreciate your suggestions. Note that contrary to this sample dataset, the actual dataset I work on is pretty large. Thank you very much!

Comment: `which.max` gives you the index. For the value just use `max`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `dplyr`, `arrange` `b` and `a` in `desc`ending order by group (`ID`) and then get the first row of each group.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  arrange(desc(b), desc(a)) %>%
  slice(1)

#   ID    a     b    
#  <fct> <fct> <fct>
#1  1     30    40
```

As shown in expected output , if we need only `ID` and `a` column we can just `select` them

```
df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  arrange(desc(b), desc(a)) %>%
  slice(1) %>%
  select(ID, a)
```

---

We can also `arrange` them in ascending order and then select last row using `n()`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  arrange(b, a) %>%
  slice(n()) %>%
  select(ID, a)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and support, it's working perfectly